# Multisite on CiviCRM with Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, multisite

I'm trying to install CiviCRM on my drupal multisite installation.
To create the multisite i used this [tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite-drupal/multi-site-in-subdirectories). As I read the [doc](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/multi-site/) for the CiviCRM multisite installation, i understood that i had to use my default site DB. Did I understand it wrong, or is there a way to use separate DBs for CiviCRM multisites ?

Thanks in advance for your advices.

Comment: are you asking if you can use a separate db for each subsite in the multisite setup?
multisite explicitly uses one db so there can be complex sharing and separation of data. if you are looking for a complete separation, look at drupal's multisite funcitonality and setup a separate civi instance for each distinct drupal site

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use the same db of drupal as well as use the separate db, civicrm gives the option to add another db.
If you want to use another db for civicrm then you have to create the db first and enter the name at time of installation , If you are first time installing civicrm use this [doc](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/drupal7/) .Civicrm use civicrm.settings.php to use the database connection,you can also check out that.

And as you said you have multisite installation you can placed the civicrm at /sites/all/modules to be accessible to all your drupal sites